# Listening To Process Erlang

Tags: erlang, file-watcher

I am trying to perform an action based on changes in the folder which are detected by **[synrc/fs library](https://github.com/synrc/fs/)**.  I want to receive this notification every time the changes captured by **fs** & perform an action e.g. printing the changed filename.

I tried below code but executes only first time!

```
say_hello() ->
    fs:start_link(fs_watcher, "/Users/foldername"),
    fs:subscribe(fs_watcher),
    receive
        {Watcher_process, {Fs, File_event}, {ChangedFile, Type}} ->
            io:format("~p was ~p ~n",[ChangedFile,File_event])
    end.
```

Any useful help is appreciated along with link & description if possible! Thanks :)

Comment: @Dogbert you both gave me kinda similar answer!! appreciate a lot!! :) I have upvoted both of your answer!!  but m confused whose answer to select (you both answer on exact time too) :|

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga you both gave me kinda similar answer!! appreciate a lot!! :) I have upvoted both of your answer!! but m confused whose answer to select (you both answer on exact time too) :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the function to keep receiving the same kind of messages you could use recursion:

```
say_hello() ->
  fs:start_link(fs_watcher, "/Users/foldername"),
  fs:subscribe(fs_watcher),
  recur().

recur()->
  receive
     {Watcher_process, {Fs, File_event}, {ChangedFile, Type}} ->
         io:format("~p was ~p ~n",[ChangedFile,File_event]),
         recur()
  end.
```

You would have to then think about a way to finalise the function.

Comment: Thanks, @Asier !! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to recursively call `receive`:

```
say_hello() ->
    fs:start_link(fs_watcher, "/Users/foldername"),
    fs:subscribe(fs_watcher),
    loop().

loop() ->
    receive
        {Watcher_process, {Fs, File_event}, {ChangedFile, Type}} ->
            io:format("~p was ~p ~n",[ChangedFile,File_event]),
            loop()
    end.
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dogbert! :)